# Trouble with filter() and find() methods

Tags: jquery, filter, find

This is a snippet from an image slider and I am trying to obtain the data attribute of what would be the currently displayed image having the style attribute "display:list-item". Since I don't know what image will be displayed I can't use the image id so I have to filter through the DOM. I have tried several approaches including the filter() method, below, but I keep coming back with either an undefined variable or an empty object.

HTML

```
<ul class="bjqs" style="height: 500px; width: 100%; display: block">
  <li class="bjqs-slide" style="height: 300px; width: 100%; display: list-item;">
    <img id="image1" data-score="0" alt="Body Condition Score 5" src="mazihealth/My Images/BCS5cropped.jpg" title="Slide1" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
    <p class="bjqs-caption" style="position:relative">
      <img id="checkmark" src="mazihealth/My Images/checkmark2.jpeg">
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JQ

```
var currimg = $('li.bjqs-slide').filter("style","display:list-item").attr('data-score');
```

Comment: Where is the HTML? Please post both so you can get a correct qualified answer.

Comment: strange, it was there when i posted.

Comment: it wasn't formatted as code, thats why it didn't show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/ZEEZP/2/

```
var currimg = $('li.bjqs-slide').filter(function() {
    return this.style['display'] == "list-item"
}).first().find("img").first().data('score');
console.log(currimg);
```

will return the `score` of the first `img` in the first `li.bjqs-slide` with a `display` of `list-item`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the score of the first `img`:

```
$(function () {
    var currimg = $('li.bjqs-slide').find('img').first().data('score');
    alert(currimg);
});
```

If you need the scores for multiple `img`s stored into an array:

```
$(function () {
    var imgScore[] = $('li.bjqs-slide').find('img').data('score');
});
```

Comment: I did not include the full code because it is repetitive but I have multiple images in the <ul>. Does that change your answer?

Comment: And you want to capture the 'score' for each of them and save them in an array?

Comment: This doesn't look for `list-item`

Comment: @smerny `list-item` is a CSS attribute for the `li` not the following `img`

Comment: Right, but he needs to get the `img` based on that.

Comment: Yes, I want to find the image that is enclosed in the <li> tag with the the attribute display:list-item.

Comment: Does the `li` that is styled with `list-item` always use the class `bjqs-slide`? If so, you don't need to qualify the `<li>` twice - just use one or the other.

Comment: yes, it always uses the class bjqs-slide. not sure what you mean by qualifying the <li> twice though.

Comment: When you traverse the DOM, you only need to find a way to uniquely identify the elements you want to include in jQuery's result set. If you use smerny's: `$('li.bjqs-slide').filter(function() {
    return this.style['display'] == "list-item"
}).first().find("img").first().data('score');`
Then you are identifying the `<li>` you want in the result set **twice**. Once with the class `.bjqs-slide`, and then again with the style property `display:list-item`. You only need one or the other.

Comment: Basically, that's a good bit of extra and unnecessary code and will result in a hit in performance. Since that `<li>` always uses the `bjqs-slide` class, that's all you need.
`$('li.bjqs-slide').find('img').first().data('score');` is all you need to get the proper result set

Answer (score 0):

.filter() is used to find elements within the results of the current query.

.find() is used to find elements within the descendants of the current results.

You're .filter call had 2 parameters, but it should only have one.  You could use $("li.bjqs-slide[style*='list-item']") to find the element whose style attribute currently contains "list-item".

You are then pulling the value of the data-score attribute from the found element, but it would appear that you should be pulling it from the contained image.